# "Created in deterministic mode" error

Tags: software-installation, make

For a particle physics project (micrOMEGAs), I have had to unpack a .tgz, and then run "make" in it (following this tutorial https://lapth.cnrs.fr/micromegas/).

I first unpacked using:

```
tar -zxvf micromegas_4.3.4.tgz
```

Then I obtained a folder `micromegas_4.3.4`, in which I ran `make`:

```
cd micromegas_4.3_4
make
```

At the end of the process, the terminal is available for next instructions, but in its last message mentions:

```
'../lib/micromegas.a' seems to have been created in deterministic mode. 
'limits.o' will always be updated. 
Please consider passing the U flag to ar to avoid the problem.
```

How do I fix this (supposedly using non-deterministic mode?)?

There are next steps to this installation process, but for the moment I just wanted to make sure that my folder `micromegas_4.3.4` has been accurately compiled using `make`, and if not, what other packages/auxiliary files would I need to add to my Ubuntu platform.

Fundamentally, I am just compiling the contents of an unpacked folder. Then this is supposed to be ready to use using the command line (no GUI involved), for physical calculations.

(This is Ubuntu 17.04 running on a VirtualBox in Windows 10 by the way.)

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I have expanded a bit on my post and its context, and provided the link to the specific setup I am supposed to follow, if that is of any help.

Answer (score 4):

The message from `ar` is a notice about the build process not an error message. As far as I understand it, it means that rebuilding the software after modification may take longer than necessary; nothing to worry about.

Comment: Understood. What about the deterministic mode? Is that a cause for concern? Because I do get problems in the ulterior parts to my coding (not mentioned in my original post) and was trying to rewind back to where I could have made any mistake(s).

Comment: @N.E.: I suggest you look up "deterministic" in the [`ar(1)` manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ar.1.html).

Comment: Apologies but I'm quite new to Ubuntu, and can't seem to figure out, in the manual you just showed me, where and if I can perform such a thing as `pass the U flag to ar`.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to change in the behavior of the ar command,  which is now configured with --enable-deterministic-archives (see [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2016/01/msg00573.html) and [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798804)).

A possible solution is to redefine the global variable for ar flags to disable deterministic archives with the U option. In the console before the make command, set

> export ARFLAGS=rvU